# How to set button in window.print() page

Tags: javascript

[image]

I want to add some buttons after the print modal was showed. Just like the picture above. Anyone give some hands? Thank you.

[w3schools demo](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_print)

Comment: That dialog is provided by the browser, you can not place any custom buttons in there from the context of your website.

Comment: @CBroe I got that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since printing is browser feature (think of client-side), you are not able to make changes/events normally in that area. Reason behind that is likely to be security (imagine a simple website printing lots of files from your printer when you are absent).

A likely solution would be opening blank page and using that page as "preview" page and add button there (you will still have to navigate user to this modal though).

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="printarea"> // The area we want to print
  <h2>The window.print() Method</h2>
  <p>Click the button to print the current page.</p>
</div> // printing area end

<button onclick="printDiv('printarea')">Print this page</button>

<script>
    function printDiv(divName)  // pass the id of which area you want to print
    {
      var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML; // get the content of printing area
      var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML; // preserving current content
      document.body.innerHTML = printContents; // overriding the body with print area content
      window.print();
      document.body.innerHTML = originalContents; // reset to original state
    }
</script>

</body>
</html
```

Process:
Before print

Comment: Thanks for answering @MD TAREK HOSSEN. But, I want to custom button. Not for print content.